# Machform integration with Salesforce

Tags: php, salesforce, machform

What I want:

I have created a form in ***machform***. Now I need to save this form data to my ***salesforce*** account somewhere (either as account or leades or contacts that's not the issue)

What I tried:

***1.*** I tried to follow this tutorial:

https://www.machform.com/blog-mailchimp-integration/

And try to send data through  ***Use Custom HTTP Headers***  but failed.

***2.*** I tried to use ***Machform->settings->send data to another website*** to do integration with salesforce, but as I said I it failed.

***3.*** I asked a question to forum also, but they didn't reply.

What I have succeeded is only create a form with input-text+radio button+textarea and save its value to machfrom itself as well as send all data to admin+registered user in mail.

Note: there is no code data so I am unable to give any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching and working on it I got a pretty simple solution (step-by-step solution given below):-

**1.** Go to your salesforce ***account->Setup***

**2.** In the left side bar click ***Customize->leads->Web-to-lead.***

**3.** Now click on ***"Create-Web-To-Lead-Form"*** button.Now you will see this window:

[image]

**4.** Now generate the form:-

[image]

**5.** When form generated ***leave that tab untouched. Don't click on any button there.***:-

[image]

**6.** We did this much only to get the unique id+url+fields name attribute through which we are going to save machForm form data to salesforce.

**7.** Now time to go to the MachForm account and under your form click edit.:-

[image]

**8.** Now we have to add a hidden field with the unique identifier which we got from the  "Web-To-Lead-Form":-

[image]

**9.** Add a hidden field into the form with the same name and value that you got from "Web-To-Lead-Form" and then save the form and click on the "I am finished" button on the pop-up:-

[image]

[image]

**10.** Now click on the notification button of that form:-

[image]

**11.** Now check the check-box  of "Send Form Data to Another Website":-

[image]

**12.** You will see a box is open under it. Now we will add things one by one

**13.** Inside the Website URL add the URL you get from "Web-To-Lead-Form":-

[image]

**14.** Skip other things and now come to Parameters. Now the name field needs to be matched to the corresponding names of "Web-To-Lead-Form" so that it can match.

```
First Name field == first_name.
Last Name field == last_name.
```

**15.** Now to get the MatchForm data for the corresponding value click on the merge tag and select a particular tag. You will get its value, copy and paste it to the corresponding column.:-

[image]

**16.** After mapping all form field values Now click on save.:-

[image]

**17.** Now close the tab where you have the "Web-to-lead" form. Now we don't have any use of that. Remind that You have to **close** it **not save it**

Now you can test your form and you will see that its data is saved to the "Leads section" inside **"SalesForce".**

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

*I've never even heard about that Machform app so take my answer with a grain of salt.*

1. See if there are any ready made integrations. Searching Salesforce AppExchange doesn't bring any results but maybe there's a Machform plugin for that?
2. Typically sending data to Salesforce requires at least 2 steps (doesn't matter which API is used):

   - send username & password, get Session Id back (and often new endpoint to which subsequent requests should be directed)
   - use this session id to insert records to Salesforce

   So unless your app has some options for multi-step forms you'll have hard time without coded solution. In a pinch the user could authenticate in SF earlier and copy-paste his session id but that's poor usability.
3. If you have a Salesforce Admin handy, he/she could create a Web-to-Lead solution in SF. it's pure configuration and at the end you're left with piece of HTML code generated by SF that you can inject to any website you wish. So you could have a look at this form, see what data it passes, to what end URL and reuse it.

   - if you go through this route make sure to not expose anywhere on the web your Salesforce Organization ID (one of hidden params in the generated form which global SF uses to route the data). You might start getting some spam if you leave it in wide open internet just like that.
   - I think ince you enable web-to-lead you can't turn it off so it'd definitely be something you want to play with first in a Developer Edition or sandbox before doing it in production.
4. If you have Salesforce Developer handy, he/she could build a "Site" (piece of Salesforce exposed to wide open web without requiring a SF user account). Or "inbound email handler" class and then your app could be sending emails to special mailbox, with form data in message's body..
5. Can it work other way around? Could Salesforce pull data from Machform, let's say every 5 minutes? The app would have to be available on the net (not in your company's intranet for example... unless you'll start the dance with security team about opening ports on firewalls, reverse proxies, demilitarized zones and all that stuff). Here a lot depends on how Machform can be exposed for integration. SOAP (WSDL)? REST?
6. Maybe you could have another database to which Machform can easily write in turn some other app would be pushing data to SF...

At least now you have some keywords you can search for in detail ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not about using any API and do some code or using db etc. BTW i got very simple solution and i already added it as an answer. Still +1 for your time and effort. Thanks