# Creating a case from Microsoft Forms into Salesforce

Tags: forms, salesforce, microsoft-forms

Is there a way to take responses filled in Microsoft Forms and create a case into Salesforce?

I have not gathered enough information to attempt this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer from SF side, you'll have to translate to MS world.

Salesforce offers somewhat dated but simple feature called web-to-case (and there's even email-to-case if for some bizarre reason it'd be easier for you). Your SF admin can enable it, decide which case fields they want to capture and SF generates 2 things:

- starts to accept the cases created this way
- generates sample html form for you

That form will be stupid. Like braindead stupid. No javascript (well, you can put recaptcha on it), minimal styling, just a bunch of fields and `<form>` that does POST to certain url. It'll show `<select>`s and stuff (of course if you add new picklist values or new records to a field that's actually a lookup on the case - you should regenerate the html, there's no magic). It's good for quick & dirty injecting into other page's code and calling it a day.

```html
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="orgid" value="00D...redacted">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://example.com">

<label for="name">Contact Name</label><input  id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="subject">Subject</label><input  id="subject" maxlength="80" name="subject" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="description">Description</label><textarea name="description"></textarea><br>

<input type="hidden"  id="external" name="external" value="1" /><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

A developer can reverse engineer a regular POST call out of that form.

And you should. As you can see I've redacted my org's ID. Spamer could use it to send you a lot of messages that way and exhaust your storage usage for example. So ideal solution would do your UI however you want, with captcha if needed, pass data to server, then your server side would make POST call to Salesforce, with org id being secret. (org id for production is very unlikely to change but if you use SF sandbox and later refresh it - it'll get new id, you'll need to update your integration)

It's bit naive but it works. If you need more (for example Case+attachments) you will have to put more leg work, make proper integration that logins to SF, maybe even runs some "describe" calls to dynamically fetch fields/picklist values/lookup records to generate the form. What's your poison, SOAP (old but you'd "consume" the WSDL file and work with classes, objects in your language) or REST...

Check out my other answers (shameless plug)

- [How to include attachments when cases are submitted via web-to-case to web-to-lead scenarios?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67980755/313628)
- [Integrate salesforce and backendless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56302073/313628) (PHP but same idea)
- [Machform integration with Salesforce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46598707/313628) (again PHP and web-to-lead which is similar feature but there's some good philosophical ranting in it)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible via MS Forms --> Sharepoint --> Salesforce Case

Comment: If possible a screenshot might be valuable